# How to specify multiple source directory for Android library project

Tags: java, android, ant, jar, compilation

I am using ant tool to build android library project,
I need to specify multiple source directory .

I have tried to specify multiple source directory by adding these lines alternatively in ant.properties file

```
source.dir=src:src2    
source.dir=src;src2
```

but unable to build in both case,
in both the cases **.class** were generated , but while creating jar file i was getting this error

`BUILD FAILED`

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:681: The following error occurred while executing this line:`

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:749:`

`C:\workarea\Android\Packages\test\src;src2 does not exist.`

can any one tell me How to specify **multiple source directory** in **ant.properties**  to build **Android library projects** ?

Comment: If you are sure that there is such a function provided by Android's build file, please check you delimeter -- maybe it's `,` instead of `;`. Otherwise, you may need to modify your build file. Please post more information here to get better help.

Comment: Not working with **,** too, May have to modify ant\build.xml file, thank you for help.

Comment: So post more content, e.g. parts of your build file & your properties file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have Solved This issue in a tricky way; Here it is

To building library-project in android with more than one source directory, first go to **ant.properties** file (for linux it is **build.properties**) and add **source.dir**

```
    source.dir=first_source_dir ;second_source_dir ; third_source_dir
```

for lib project , **ant** creates the **jar** library with compiled **.class** files from the directory  **bin/classes** of **out.dir** directory specified in **ant.properties** or **build.properties** file;

While creating  **jar** , **ant** removes all **.java** source file form the **jar**, which may be included with the **jar** if coder keeps any **.java** source file in **out.dir** directory, and specify that directory  in **source.dir** ;

Now to removing those **.java** source **ant** goes to the **source.dir** directory with the following command

```
        <property name="source.absolute.dir" location="${source.dir}" />
        dir="${source.absolute.dir}"
```

With this command **ant** actually trying to go the directory

```
cd   <your_project_root_dir>/first_source_dir ;second_source_dir ; third_source_dir
```

which is not present ...

**Solution:**

step 1. At first make sure that your **source directory** (source.dir) and **build directory** ( out.dir ) are different;

step 2. go to  C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant  open **build.xml**
then go to **jar** tag

```
    <jar destfile="${out.library.jar.file}">                        
       <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
         includes="**/*.class"
         excludes="${project.app.package.path}/R.class ${project.app.package.path}/R$*.class ${project.app.package.path}/Manifest.class ${project.app.package.path}/Manifest$*.class ${project.app.package.path}/BuildConfig.class"/>
       <fileset dir="${source.absolute.dir}" excludes="**/*.java ${android.package.excludes}" />
   </jar>
```

Now comment or remove the last **fileset** tag in **jar** tag

```
    <jar destfile="${out.library.jar.file}">                        
       <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
            includes="**/*.class"
            excludes="${project.app.package.path}/R.class ${project.app.package.path}/R$*.class ${project.app.package.path}/Manifest.class ${project.app.package.path}/Manifest$*.class ${project.app.package.path}/BuildConfig.class"/>
       <!--fileset dir="${source.absolute.dir}" excludes="**/*.java ${android.package.excludes}" /-->
    </jar>
```

Now build your project ;

Comment: Does this have to be done in ant.properties file?  Can't it be done in build.xml?

Comment: I find it ridiculous that I have to modify the build.xml file. Are you sure this is correct? Why isn't android handling semicolons/colons anymore?

Comment: To clarify, this build.xml is located in the Android SDK.  Which is NOT located in my version control repository.  So how would you manage this with multiple developers.  It doesn't make sense to have everyone modify their SDK tools does it?

Comment: @AshokSoThree you can copy the Android ``build.xml`` into your project renamed as ``android_patched_build.xml``, then modify your ``build.xml`` to include this other file instead of the one from ``${sdk.dir}``.

Answer (score 9):

This did the trick for me without modifying SDK files:

ant.properties:

```
source.absolute.dir = tmp-src
```

custom_rules.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="CustomRules">
    <target name="-pre-build" >
        <copy todir="tmp-src" >
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**" />
            <fileset dir="src-1" includes="**" />
            <fileset dir="src-2" includes="**" />
            <fileset dir="src-3" includes="**" />
            <fileset dir="src-4" includes="**" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="-post-build" >
        <delete dir="tmp-src" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Modifying the SDK files is completely bad news.

Comment: This works for me perfect as well. This is the best solution if you just need to attach additional source folders to a build.

Comment: This is the solution, not what has been selected as selected solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a dir (say build_src) in your project dir.
2. go into that dir (cd build_src)
3. Create soft links (ln -s TARGET linkname) in build_src to all the source directories you want to include
   eg: if your original problem is to include src1, src2 along with standard src dir, create src1, src2 softlinks to those under build_src
4. create ant.properties with source.dir=build_src

This worked fine for me and I think is the cleanest approach (also since those are soft links to actual source, you don't have multiple copies of source)

1. One of my project had .aidl files and AIDL complained. Instead of creating softlink to src, I created softlink to src/com and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

At least on later versions of the build tools, the problem is that the value put into this property gets passed into a `<property name="source.absolute.dirs" location="source.dirs"/>`. The `location` attribute doesn't know how to deal with colon / semicolon-separated paths.

The fix is very simple, just use:

```
source.absolute.dirs=src1:src2:src3
```

etc., as opposed to:

```
source.dirs=src1:src2:src3
```