# Android Library Project JAR from ANT

Tags: android, ant, android-library, android-build

I read in this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html that I can create a .JAR file for a library project that I could distribute it for external people to leverage.

Where can I find documentation on how I can create this Library Jar?

Does anyone know the steps I need to do via ANT to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc to create lib project...

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

and here

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

check this for additional info

[How to specify multiple source directory for Android library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605899/how-to-specify-multiple-source-directory-for-android-library-project)